# How can I use react native time picker?

Tags: react-native

I am unable to solve this issue no matter what packages I use for time picker. My react native version is 0.64.1 and my react version is 16.13.1[image]

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the package and then `npx react-native run-android`?

Comment: I have tried once... Let me do it again